# Formatting date on the fly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am receiving a value that I wish to strip of garbage, then pass to Angular's date format feature.

This is what I get:

```
/Date(1481328000000)/
```

I'd like `ng-repeat` to strip everything that's not the number, create a date from it then use:

```
<td>{{match.delivery_deadline_date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
```

In my `ng-repeat` directive. Is there anywhere I can specify to run a custom function that would strip the garbage before it tries to format it ?.

I've looked around and anything I googled ends up being about running code once `ng-repeat` is done, not running custom code on each rendered record.

Comment: You can use `myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,'');` to strip everything other than numbers.

Comment: @ChrisWissmach Yes, I know how to do that in javascript, but how do I tell  angular to invoke that code on each rendered records ?

Comment: You can write your own filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: @CyberAleks OK, filter was what I needed. Googling 'renderer' was not productive, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always pass it a filter function.
`<td>{{match.delivery_deadline_date | dateFilter}}</td>`

Then you would have a date filter function that sorts the date the way you want it.

```
angular.module('module.name')
  .filter('dateFilter', function () {
    return function (dateInputHere) {
       \\do some manipulation please
    }
  }
});
```